# rectangle width(probably easy to answer) VB

Tags: vb.net, variables, resize

```
Dim energybar As New Rectangle(9, 154, energy, 21)
```

That is my new rectangle, now when I draw it

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, energybar)
```

It says there is no width but the integer energy is = to 100...

now, how do I fix this? It but be somewhat simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. I put it in a Form_Paint event which resulted in the Image below. I would strongly suspect that your energy variable's value is the problem. Make sure that if the variable is not declared in the `Paint` method that you make it a `Class` Scoped variable:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim energy As Integer = 100
    Dim energybar As New Rectangle(9, 154, energy, 21)

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, energybar)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I found out the problem, the energy.width was needed to be in .paint

Comment: @RyanBlevins What object type is energy

Comment: It is an integer, but it is a class variable, not a paint variable, so I had to add "energybar.Width = energy" to my paint sub.

Comment: @RyanBlevins if the variable is declared in the same Class as the Paint Sub it should still work, since the Paint Sub still has visibility of the variable. But anyhow I am glad it is working for you.